# Deciding on port value of messenger service which is not XMPP based

Tags: networking, xmpp, protocols, ports

I am going to launch new messenger service. However, it is not XMPP based. Instead I am using my own protocol (for certain reasons).
What I am not able to decide on is what port shall I use for this service. A typical XMPP based messenger uses port 5222. Shall I use the same or different port?

Here are pros and cons I can think of...

If I use same port 5222 like other XMPP messengers, being standard port for messenger service my service will also use same port (But are there any cons here for my protocol being non-XMPP?)

If I use some other port, I fear that many firewalls will not allow traffic on non-standard port. Also anti-spywares too might flag my application as suspicious.

Please I need advice from experts.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your protocol into TLS connection on 443 port: it will be never blocked by firewalls (just because https connections uses this in the same way) and TLS traffic cannot be identified by "anti-spyware" software